# Cannot initialize a pointer using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++14, new-operator, unique-ptr

I have an object inside my class and I have declared the object without any initialization:

```
std::unique_ptr<tf::TransformBroadcaster> tfb_;
```

Then, during the construction, I have decided to initialize my `tfb_`:

```
tfb_ = std::make_unique<tf::TransformBroadcaster>(new tf::TransformBroadcaster());
```

I am getting an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘tf::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster(tf::TransformBroadcaster*)’
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
```

From my understanding, it looks like I am trying to pass an argument even though I am not (or may be?). The header file of `tf::TransformBroadcaster` is nothing special (just a snippet):

```
class TransformBroadcaster{
public:
  /** \brief Constructor (needs a ros::Node reference) */
  TransformBroadcaster();
```

I have tried to use a raw pointer in my header file:

```
tf::TransformBroadcaster* tfb_;
```

and in my constructor:

```
tfb_ = new TransformBroadcaster()
```

and it worked. Any idea why?

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's not clear to me what you mean, but I interpreted as saying `std::unique_ptr` must be initialized to some value like references. But `std::unique_ptr` has a default constructor that constructs it with `nullptr`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl A `unique_ptr` can be default-constructed and then initialized with a pointer separately via its `reset()` or `operator=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As there is no constructor of `TransformBroadcaster` that takes a `TransformBroadcaster*` as input, you cannot call `std::make_unique<TransformBroadcaster>()` with such an argument.

In short, this line:

```
tfb_ = std::make_unique<tf::TransformBroadcaster>(new tf::TransformBroadcaster());
```

should be this:

```
tfb_ = std::make_unique<tf::TransformBroadcaster>();
```

Comment: So, if I will not pass any argument to make_unique, it will create a pointer instance itself?

Comment: Yes, the part within `()` are the arguments to the constructor of the type you want to create a smart pointer  for. `tfb_ = std::make_unique<tf::TransformBroadcaster>()` would use the default constructor.

Comment: @aikhs `make_unique` *always* makes a pointer to a new instance. You just give it the arguments you want it to use to construct that instance.

Comment: @aikhs You *never* use `new` with `std::make_unique()`.  If you want to use `new`, it would need to look like this instead: `tfb_ = std::unique_ptr<tf::TransformBroadcaster>(new tf::TransformBroadcaster);` or `tfb_.reset(new tf::TransformBroadcaster);` Using `make_unique()` is safer, though.